# How can I use WixUI to select a server to run a script on Installation

Tags: sql, database, installation, wix, wixsharp

Im using Wix# to deploy our software which needs to run an SQL script to install the database on installation.

However I would like to give the user the option to select the server to install the database on, or install a new server instance to run the script on.

I have looked into creating custom UI for the installer, as well as running SQL scripts and chaining other installations with the setup, but so far I couldn't figure out how to make the UI communicate with the setup.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data you're working with you can store in properties. [Here's stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668723/wix-toolset-how-to-set-a-property) about setting properties and binding them to controls.
So if you want user to type name of database - just do it as described.

But if you wat to show combobox with server list - it will be little bit harder. You should add combo box element, for example:

```
<Control Type="ComboBox" Id="id" Width="10" Height="10" X="10" Y="10" Property="SELECTED_SERVER">
```

And after that you'll have two options:

1. [Here's an option to manually populate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016100/wix-combobox-populating-values/19704360)
2. [Here's an option to populate it dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657788/wix-dot-net-managed-custom-action-dynamically-fill-combo-box-with-sql-server-i). In this case you should run that custom action before you show combo box - for example on [next click of previous window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227368/wix-custom-action-call-after-next) or after installer was just started.

Anyway, your property (SELECTED_SERVER) will be binded to that control and you can easily use it in your [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096573/how-can-i-use-wix-properties-in-a-sql-file-executed-from-the-installer) or [custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101579/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-custom-action) later.